# Copying facebook-ios-sdk and configuring the Xcode project

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, github, xcode4.5, facebook-ios-sdk

I have gone through this document :[Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for iOS v3.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/)

I have successfully configured my Xcode project by following it.
But I want to do it without adding the Facebook.framework.
As previously we used to only add the "src" folder which we used to clone from :[Facebook SDK for iOS - Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). Why can't I just copy the "src" folder and configure my project.
I want to play around with FBFriendPickerViewController.m (dot m) file. Which I am not able to view if I follow the standard tutorial. But is available in the "src" folder.
Please how can I do that ? And it also seems that FbGraph.h file doesn't exist.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to play with the source, go to:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/

After getting the code, run this script to build the framework locally:

```
<Install Location>/scripts/build_framework.sh
```

This will drop the framework in the folder:

```
<Install Location>/build
```

Follow the same instructions in the Getting Started to include the Facebook SDK, however, you will get the framework from your local build folder.

Note: You'll likely have to modify the build search path in Xcode if you're swapping out, say one of the sample projects (that was looking for the Framework in a particular place).

Comment: The SDK GitHub download location.

Comment: I have successfully done that . But the FBFriendPickerViewController.m (dot m) file is no where to be seen in the FacebookSDK.framework folder. How can I get all .m files in my Xcode project ?

Comment: You can't see it inside the framework. You would have to open up the src/facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj to see the files. I haven't tried this, but you could try pulling in this src folder into your project instead of adding the framework.